# Test folder structure for angular 4 unit testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am using angular-cli for my app, In my unit testing i have 4 different type of files.

1. file which contains all the test
2. test helpers
3. TestHostComponent to test components with input and output
4. stubs for services

Which extensions i should use for above files(like *.spec.ts,*.test.ts, *.stub.ts). And should i create a different module to declare my TestHostComponent as it gives error when not declared in any module.
I tried to exclude all these files by adding them to tsconfig.app.json, but still these files were compiled during build, how can i exclude them?